# Porting POSIX regex to Lua pattern - unexpected results

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have hard time porting POSIX regex to Lua string patterns.

I'm dealing with html response from which I would like to filter checkboxes
that are checked. Particularly I'm interested in `value` and `name` fields of
each checked checkbox:

Here are examples of checkboxes I'm interested in:

```
<input class="rid-2 form-checkbox" id="edit-2-access-comments" name="2[access comments]" value="access comments" checked="checked" type="checkbox">

<input class="rid-3 form-checkbox real-checkbox" id="edit-3-administer-comments" name="3[administer comments]" value="administer comments" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```

as opposed I'm not interested in this (unchecked checkbox):

```
<input class="rid-2 form-checkbox" id="edit-2-access-printer-friendly-version" name="2[access printer-friendly version]" value="access printer-friendly version" type="checkbox">
```

Using POSIX regex I've used following pattern in Python: `pattern=r'name="(.*)" value="(.*)" checked="checked"'` and it just worked.

My first approach in Lua was simply to use this: `pattern ='name="(.-)"
value="(.-)" checked="checked"'` but it gave strange results (first capture
was as expected but the second one returned lots of unneeded html).

I've also tried following pattern:

`pattern = 'name="(%d?%[.-%])" value="(.-)"%s?(c?).-="?c.-"%s?type="checkbox"'`

This time, in second capture content of `value` was returned but all
checkboxes where matched (not only those with `checked="checked"` field)

For completeness, here's the Lua code (snippet from my Nmap NSE script) that
attempts to do this pattern matching:

```
  pattern = 'name="(.-)" value="(.-)" checked="checked"' 
  data = {}
  for name, value in string.gmatch(res.body, pattern) do
    stdnse.debug(1, string.format("%s %s", name, value))
  end
```

Comment: `pattern = 'name="([^"]*)" value="([^"]*)" checked="checked"'`

Comment: Thanks Egor it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

> I've used following pattern in Python: `pattern=r'name="(.*)" value="(.*)" checked="checked"'` and it just worked.

Python `re` is not POSIX compliant and `.` matches any char but a newline char there (in POSIX and Lua, `.` matches any char including a newline).

If you want to match a string that has 3 attributes above one after another, you should use something like

```
local pattern = 'name="([^"]*)"%s+value="([^"]*)"%s+checked="checked"'
```

Why not `[^\r\n]-`? Because in case there are two tags on one line with the first having the first and/or second attribute and the second having the second and third or just second (and even if there is a third tag with the third attribute while the first one contains the first two attributes), there will be match, as `[^\r\n]` matches `<` and `>` and can "overfire" across the tags.

Note that `[^"]*`, a negated bracket expression, will only match 0+ chars other than `"` thus restricting the matches within one tag.

See [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/sLYCeW):

```
local rx = 'name="([^"]*)"%s+value="([^"]*)"%s+checked="checked"'
local s = '<li name="n1"\nvalue="v1"><li name="n2"\nvalue="v1" checked="checked"><li name="n3"\nvalue="v3"   checked="checked">'
for name, value in string.gmatch(s, rx) do
  print(name, value)
end
```

Output:

```
n2  v1
n3  v3
```

Answer (score 0):

(Updated based on comments) The pattern doesn't work when a line that doesn't have `checked="checked"` is before a line with `checked="checked"` in the input as `.-` expression captures unnecessary parts. There are several ways to avoid this; one suggested by @EgorSkriptunoff is to use `([^"]*)` as the pattern; another is to exclude new lines `([^\r\n]-)`. The following example prints what you expect:

```
local s = [[
<input class="rid-2 form-checkbox" id="edit-2-access-comments" name="2[access comments]" value="access comments" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
<input class="rid-2 form-checkbox" id="edit-2-access-printer-friendly-version" name="2[access printer-friendly version]" value="access printer-friendly version" type="checkbox">
<input class="rid-3 form-checkbox real-checkbox" id="edit-3-administer-comments" name="3[administer comments]" value="administer comments" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
]]
local pattern = 'name="([^\r\n]-)" value="([^\r\n]-)" checked="checked"' 
for name, value in string.gmatch(s, pattern) do
  print(name, value)
end
```

The output:

```
2[access comments]  access comments
3[administer comments]  administer comments
```

Comment: You will see the problem if first item is unchecked (doesn't have `checked="checked"`) and second item is checked.

Comment: Right; then new lines or quotes need to be forbidden in the pattern as @EgorSkriptunoff suggested earlier.